# How to maximize the cpu usage when using Jupyter Lab on M1 Mac

Tags: python, macos, jupyter, apple-m1

I noticed that my Mac with M1 Max does not make maximum usage of CPU.
I am learning ML reading "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow".
I "Run All Cells"ed on this notebook.
https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml3/blob/main/03_classification.ipynb
My activity monitor showed that the cpu usage was around 10 - 20 %. The temperature of Mac was mild.

[Low usage on activity monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9qYv.png)

In contrast to it, when I am executing simple benchmark code, CPU usage jumps up to 97% and my Mac got hot.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/695963

```
import time
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
a = np.random.uniform(size=(300, 300))
runtimes = 10

timecosts = []
for _ in range(runtimes):
    s_time = time.time()
    for i in range(100):
        a += 1
        np.linalg.svd(a)
    timecosts.append(time.time() - s_time)

print(f'mean of {runtimes} runs: {np.mean(timecosts):.5f}s')
```

[High usage on activity monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kvUv.png)

I would like to know if there is a way to make my Mac work hardly and become hottest even if running Jupyter Lab.

"nice" command and "High Performance" battery usage on System settings did not give me the change.

Comment: Well probably the CPU is not the bottleneck.

Comment: Have any thgouthts?

Comment: Thoughts on what? There is nothing wrong with what you wrote. There are many things which limit the speed of some application on a computer. One of them is the bottleneck and works at 100%, while others don't. Do you also ask why your SSD in not 100% full or your RAM, or why the PSU only takes 400W of power when it can handle 1000W? If you want your CPU to be at 100%, buy a cheaper CPU.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by my self.
Many of scikit-learn functions which are contained in the notebook have n_jobs parameter. When I set to -1, which means doing core optimization, CPU usage jumped up to very high level.
This is before -1.

[without n_job ssetting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYrUY.png)

And this is after.

[with n_job setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDV6L.png)

My cpu has 10 core, so 947% is nealy 100%.

Total execution time reduced from 1485s to 472s.